# List of all CREATE operations I made on level of phpMyAdmin or MySQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

When I am doing something in a schema of tables I want to have a list of changes to put in svn, and execute it by another members of the team. As I understand, there are 2 ways: extract from logs, or implant some code inside phpMyAdmin, maybe there are other ways without coding?

Answer (score 1):

well - you can periodically run

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -A --no-data
```

diff it with previous dump and if needed commit to svn. you might want to add some info who was recently accessing phpmyadmin [ if you use httpauth - you could extract it from apache logs with some hackery ].

anyway - analyzing mysql logs seems most reasonable to me.

Comment: No. Diff not give me Alter statements.

Comment: @dynback.com - not alter statemens but still good idea what was going on.